# Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v0.10.37 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-4

While trying localhost:3000 , it throws error as

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v0.10.37. Update it.):
```

I have tried to update node, but there is not update available.

```
node -v # v8.1.3
nodejs -v # v0.10.37
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3', and others
```

Gemfile.lock

```
autoprefixer-rails (9.1.1)
```

Comment: It need not be an issue specific to `auto-prefixer`, it could also be one of the `dependencies` causing it. Can you paste your Gemfile.lock ?

Comment: v0.10.37 is an ancient version, it seems that you have latest LTS version (8) installed but nodejs binary points to a wrong version. Run `which node` and `which nodejs` in terminal and post the result here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was fixed by adding [`gem 'mini_racer'`](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer) into your gemfile.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that the **autoprefixer** was installed as a dependency of another package, but without specifying the version, so the installed version was 9.4.3, which had a conflict with my local Node installation.

I fixed it by adding an specific version for the package in my GemFile, and running **bundle install**

```
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 7.1.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and the issue was that I had leftover nodejs executable from a random installation a while ago.
see here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/issues/162#issuecomment-440220624
I removed that by doing this in the terminal `git rm -rf /usr/bin/nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

If you just scaffolded a new rails project, check your `Gemfile` for the line with

`# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby`

and uncomment it. You should then have

`gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby`

Run `bundle update`

This worked for me. Just like Karl mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was found when running SemaphoreCI.

The problem was that ExecJS (a dependency) has a way of setting Node that causes a problem. The problem lies in the initialization of Node as follows:

```
module ExecJS
  module Runtimes
    Node = ExternalRuntime.new(
      name:        "Node.js (V8)",
      command:     ["nodejs", "node"], # This line has the problem
      runner_path: ExecJS.root + "/support/node_runner.js",
      encoding:    'UTF-8'
    )
  end
end
```

So I changed the way Node was initialized by setting this at the bottom of the `application.rb` file.

```
module ExecJS
  module Runtimes
    Node = ExternalRuntime.new(
      name:        "Node.js (V8)",
      command:     ["node", "nodejs"], # This is how to initialize Node
      runner_path: ExecJS.root + "/support/node_runner.js",
      encoding:    'UTF-8'
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) you might need to set the default node version to a more recent version.

`nvm install node # Install the latest available version`

`nvm alias default node # Always default to the latest available node version on a shell`